# How to best use a bunch of importxml formulas triggered at the same time

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 9 Google spreadsheets. Each of those files has 8 sheets. Each of those sheets has 1-5 importxml formulas that retrieves data from an api. Every api query uses costly credits, and leaving the importxmlformula as it is, uses way too much credits as it refreshes every 30/60min and i only need the data once a day.

So i added a named range with a refresh boolean. My google apps script sets this boolean at 6am to true, only if this is true, the importxml formulas work.
Example:

```
=IF(REFRESH = TRUE, IMPORTXML("https://api.sistrix.com/links.overview?" & API_KEY & "&" & DOMAIN, "//@num"))
```

Another google apps script, triggered an hour later, copies all the cell contents to another sheet an puts a date behind it, so i archived it for long term.

My problem tho, there are 300+ importxml formulas, triggered at the exact same time. A part of them are stuck in loading, an even an hour later, my archive script only copies #ERROR! values for those.

I tried using triggers for the scripts at different times, so i dont overload the api, but this didnt help. Then i added another refresh boolean to independently set a few importxml fomrulas at time X, and the other ones at time Y, but this didnt help either.

Do you have any ideas how i could increase the performance or how i could minimize the formulas executed at one time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could these calls be made from apps script and with only one call get all the information needed and then organize it into the different sheets?

Comment: You don't overload the API. You overload IMPORTXML quota limits. It gets slow when you have many imports but I can't remember exact rules.